# Windows BAT file SET command works in weird way - Python virtual environment activate script

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, virtualenv

I'm trying to add some variables into Python virtual environment activate.bat. 
I supposed it's a regular BAT file with pretty expected behaviour. But what I see is weird.

```
set env=abc

set db_url=dfg
```

If I do **echo %env%** after in the command prompt I see:

```
abcset db_url=dfg
```

Who can explain why is that and how to fix it?

Also, if I try clear it up like

```
set env=
```

it just reads all the strings after.

UPD: Okay, I don't know what I've done but what worked:

1. I recreated the virtual environment
2. I opened all files in VS Code (not in Notepad++ as before)
3. I put all the variables sets into double quotes like set "env=dev"

Comment: Probably a line-ending issue such as using `LF` rather than `CRLF` - that would likely combine all those "lines" into one.

Comment: @paxdiablo I thought the same :( but I didn't know why it happened. Is Notepad++ some bad for these tasks?

Comment: Depends on how Notepad++ is configured. Edit -> EOL Conversion should be set to "Windows (CR LF)" and Encoding should be set to "Encode in ANSI."

Comment: Try `echo %env%>somefile.txt`, then check the content of `somefile.txt`, perhaps in hex. view; I'm quite sure there is a CR, like `abc` + CR + `set db_url=dfg`...

Comment: @SomethingDark everything is exactly as you described.